# resource not found - unable to find resource with velocity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

Unsure why i am getting this error - i can't see what is wrong with my config.

the reference to what file to use is in the notification.properties file which is referenced in my config:

> classpath:com/app/application/notification/notifications

my app runs fine and looks inside the notificaitons.properties file for new.user.password.template=en/newuserpassword.html

I have debugged it and it is finding 'en/newuserpassword.html' fine but then it cant find the actual file itself.

i have checked and the file is definetly there - exactly matches but just can't find it:

> resources/com/app/application/notification/template/en/newuserpassword.html

> org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'en/newuserpassword.html'
> at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
> at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
> at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
> at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:343)
> at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:320)

```
 <bean id="notificationResolver" class="com..application.notification.resolver.VelocityNotificationResolver">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.context.TypeConvertingReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
                <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60" />
                <property name="basenames">
                    <list>
                        <value>classpath:com/app/application/notification/notifications</value>
                        <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/enums</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine">
                <constructor-arg ref="velocityProperties"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

i have a similar setup for auditing messages which works fine and the templates are found

```
    <bean id="auditMessageResolver" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.audit.domain.VelocityAuditMessageResolver">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.application.util.spring.context.TypeConvertingReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
                <property name="basenames">
                    <list>
                        <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/enums</value>
                        <value>classpath:com/app/application/audit/auditing</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine">
                <constructor-arg ref="velocityProperties"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your template is on the classpath as `com/app/application/notification/template/en/newuserpassword.html`

And you are asking velocity to find `en/newuserpassword.html`

Then your template location should be `com/app/application/notification/template`

Instead of `com/app/application/notification/notifications`

Comment: so the notification.properties file is what i am referencing here - 

com/app/application/notification/notifications

the template file is stored where you have said, except you're just missing the /en

com/app/application/notification/en/template

Answer (score 0):

this was a dumb fault on my behalf but hopefully it may highlight issues to anyone in the future reading this.

my notificaitons config referenced to a velocity properties which was pointing to the auditing templates. It was so blatantly obvious that i didnt even notice it.

```
<util:properties id="velocityPropertiesNotifications">
    <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
    <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader</prop>
    <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat9.0.76/webapps/my-app/WEB-INF/classes/com/application/notification/templates</prop>
</util:properties>
```

i just added a new properties which pointed at the right directory where my templates are stored - this resolved the not found error.